# Edit and Ask profiles in reverse order on web vs app

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app

I am a regular use of SE both on the web and on iOS App.  I find it confusing that when reading a question on the web the asker's profile is on the right and the editor's profile is on the left while unexpectedly (to me at least) in the iOS App (and I'm guessing the Android one) the positions of these profile boxes are reversed.

I am alway mistaking the the editor for the asker on iOS.

Some annotated screenshots to illustrate my point:

Asker only on web... flush right.  Nice!
[image: Ask on web]

Asker only on iOS... flush left.  Nice!
[image: Ask on iOS]

Ask and edit on web... edit added to the left.  OK.
[image: Edit on web]

Ask and edit on iOS... edit added to the right.  Yuck.  This reverses the position on the web and confuses AllInOne.
[image: Edit on iOS]

Comment: The colored backgrounds have always given me enough context to not be confused.

Comment: @Catija honest to Pete I never knew that's what the backgrounds signified!  Thanks for the tip. In any case it's too subtle imo to pass visually impaired tests (aside from the clueless like myself).

Comment: Note that there is no active development on the apps anymore so nothing is likely to change any time soon

Comment: @cai yes appears to be dupe. I really did look for this question before asking tho.  Thanks!

Comment: Btw, the Android app doesn't even show who edited the post

Comment: @ABochur it shows the user who made the last edit, it does not have a revisions list.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess it's different by me. It tells be the time that the post was last edited, but it only shows who the original poster was. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ0WP.jpg) a screenshot of the same post as shown above, where Jeff Atwood made the edit, but it still shows the original posters name

Comment: @ABochur oh... you're right.